# DLookUp behavior in Form_Current with Label Captions

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, lookup, caption

Access 2010 here.

Ok, Dlookups appear behave different based on where they are used. I have this Dlookup 
inside a ClockNo_AferUpdate() subroutine that works well on new form entries to change a label's caption to what is found in the "Employees" DB under "EmployeeName" field based on the entered "ClockNo" in a ClockNo combo-box:

```
Me.LabelName1.Caption = DLookup("[EmployeeName]", "Employees", "[ClockNo] =" & Forms![InspectionEntryForm]!ClockNo)
```

The Employees database has four fields: AutoNumber-type "ID," Number-type "ClockNo," Text-type "Shift," and Text-type "EmployeeName."

***Re-EDIT:***

The RowSource for the ClockNo combo box as it sources from the Employees database:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW [ClockNo], [EmployeeName] FROM [Employees] ORDER BY [ClockNo];
```

***END Re-EDIT***

What I am looking for is the same functionality in Form_Current() so browsing through older entries preserves the Label's caption based on the entered ClockNo. Unfortunately, simply re-using the above Dlookup gives a "Run-time error '3075': Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[ClockNo] ='."

Attaching the Dlookup as a control source to a text box does work O.K, but labels seem to be the best use here. I have mucked about with the Criteria section of the Dloopkup for some time without any real success.

End goal is to have a simple label next to a combo box that displays the employee's name based on their current and past ClockNo entries. The name is stored in a separate Employees database alongside their clock number and their shift.

This should be quite simple as both the ClockNo entry and the Label operate on the same form with the same database. Thanks for your input!

Comment: '[EmployeeName]' has been added to the selection source in the edit above. Sourcing '[EmployeeName]' without a Dlookup through the ClockNo Combo box RowSource is done how? (I've tried a few types of syntax I'm familiar with to access other types of objects) Thanks for the help!

Comment: Oh, I had just given the Row Source as-is with no edits. I did edit it on my side (the comment), sorry for the confusion. It is now setup for `[EmployeeName]` and `[ClockNo]`, as I really don't need `[ID]`. What I am trying to figure out is grabbing a reference to the `[EmployeeName]` in VBA after the ClockNo Combo box is updated. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a combo box named `ClockNo` with this as its Row Source:

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW [ClockNo], [EmployeeName]
FROM [Employees]
ORDER BY [ClockNo];
```

I'm not sure why you want `DISTINCTROW` there.  I would have suspected `DISTINCT` to be more appropriate.  But I don't think it matters.

The important point is that the combo already includes `[EmployeeName]`, so you shouldn't need to use `DLookup` to fetch `[EmployeeName]` again.  Simply read the value from the second column of the combo's selected row.

Imagine your form includes a text box named `txtEmployeeName`.  In the form's current event, you could do this:

```
Me.txtEmployeeName = Me.ClockNo.Column(1)
```

Notice the column index numbers start with 0, so the second column is `.Column(1)`.

And you could do the same thing in the combo's After Update event.

Finally, you wanted to change a label's `.Caption`, but I showed you how to change a text box's `.Value`.  If you can't make this technique work with the label, just use a text box instead.  You can set the text box's `Enabled` property to `No` and adjust its other properties so that it is visually indistinguishable from a label.

Another approach could be simpler still.  If you want to keep `[ClockNo]` as the combo's bound value, but are willing to display `[EmployeeName]` as the combo's selected value, you can set the width of the first column (`[ClockNo]`) to zero.  You would still see both `[ClockNo]` and `[EmployeeName]` in the dropdown.  If this is acceptable, you wouldn't need to bother with a label or text box.

Comment: Ok. I was messing around with the "Column Count" assigned to the Combo box and figured addressing `[EmployeeName]` had to do with columns (the 2 columns in the drop down _almost_ met my needs). Thank you so much! Syntax to remember!

Comment: You're welcome.  I added another suggestion, but uncertain whether it fits your needs.

Comment: I'll look into that. It would provide a more streamlined look to the form for sure. Thank you!